# adding onclick to elements dynamically, passing function parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a preloaded page and I am trying to add onclick event to all the nodes with a specific class name. But the function in the onclick should use the element node in it.

```
var elemArr=document.getElementsByClassName('ABC');

    for(var i=0;i<elemArr.length;i++){

        elemArr[i].onclick = function()
        {
            console.log(elemArr[i]);  // This is being returned as undefined
            // How can I use elemArr[i] here 
        };
    }
```

I tried

```
for(var i=0;i<elemArr.length;i++){

    printObj=elemArr[i];
    elemArr[i].onclick = function()
    {
        console.log(printObj);
        var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, printObj);
        console.log(newObject );
    };
}
```

but didn't work.I feel the above won't work anyway. How do I solve this problem..?

Comment: You have to use JavaScript Closures: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: All your handlers are sharing the same `i` variable, which by the time your handler is called, will have the value of `elemArr.length` See the linked question. Simplest solution `for(var i=0;i<elemArr.length;i++){

        elemArr[i].onclick = (function(index) {
          return function(e){ 
             console.log(elemArr[index]) 
          }
        })(i);`

Comment: @KarlenKishmiryan The OP is already using closures ;) The problem is that the OP is sharing a closure

Comment: For consistency in code, when using jQuery, use it ;)

Comment: ... and you would automatically avoid closure problem with jQuery.

Comment: @dfsq You wouldn't automatically fix it `$(elemArr[i]).click(function() {console.log(elemArr[i]); };`

Comment: @JuanMendes But that's not the way you should code it using jQuery

Comment: @JuanMendes I can't see any closure OP used. In my answer I have created a demo using closures, which works fine.

Comment: @JuanMendes I mean proper jQuery usage: `$('.ABC').click(function() { console.log(this) })` :)

Comment: @dfsq My example shows that just using jQuery doesn't fix it. "Proper" JavaScript usage also fixes it

Comment: @KarlenKishmiryan All the event handlers use `i` from a closure

Comment: @KarlenKishmiryan Where the word `function` there is a closure. Always :)

Comment: Hmm.. but the `onclick` handler is being attached to `elemsArr[i]`, not to the `printObj`. So what's the purpose of `printObj`?

Comment: @dfsq Not always, only when there is a function inside of a function. Also, note that if the inner function doesn't use any of the variables in the outer function, Chrome does not create a closure. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14987697/227299

Comment: @JuanMendes `$('.ABC').on('click', function(){console.log(this);});` What's wrong there?

Comment: @A.Wolff Nothing, you could also use `this` in plain JavaScript, but you can't use `i` from the closure even in jQuery. I'm just saying there are ways to botch this, even with jQuery as I've shown in my example

Comment: @JuanMendes Always. Closure is a function with the scope it was created in. So any function has access to some scope. This access is a closure.

Comment: @dfsq Did you see the link I posted? Local variables go on the stack, and a closure is only created (plain local variables are on the stack) when you have an inner function. Be sure to look at the post I linked

Comment: @JuanMendes I think we are arguing about definitions. You are talking about something else probably.

Comment: No, I'm just saying that JavaScript still uses a stack for local variables, closures are only needed to enclose local variables that would otherwise go out of scope (not in your current stack frame), functions within functions. The chrome debugger shows three different scopes: local (stack), closures, and global.

Comment: @JuanMendes Thx, very instructive!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should wrap your code inside of `loop` with a `function` so that a new copy of `i` is created for each of your event handlers, like this.

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('elem');

if (elems.length) {
  for (var i = 0, l = elems.length; i < l; i++) {
    (function(i) {
      elems[i].onclick = function() {
        alert('Element #' + i);
      }
    })(i);
  }
}

// Could also use bind for slighlty cleaner code
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

for (var i = 0, l = elems.length; i < l; i++) {
  elems[i].onmousedown = (function(index, e) {
    console.log('MouseDown - Element  #' + index);
  }).bind(elems[i], i);
}
```

```html
<div class="elem">Elem #1</div>
<div class="elem">Elem #2</div>
<div class="elem">Elem #3</div>
```